# How to automate Websphere MQ installation in windows?

Tags: ibm-mq

I have been working on MQ installation in last couple of weeks. Now I need to automate MQ 7.5 installation using chef or powershell scripts. MQ installation for unix I got this URL https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-chef through chef. For windows I am not sure how to automate ? Please guide me or send me any articles to do that. Thanks advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IBM MQ 7.5 Knowledge center page "[Advanced installation using msiexec](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q008690_.htm)" documents how to perform a automated install.

> **Example**
>
> Here is an example of a typical msiexec command. All parameters,
>   separated by one or more spaces, must be typed on the same line as the
>   msiexec call.
>
> ```
> msiexec
> /i path\MSI\IBM WebSphere MQ.msi
> /l*v c:\install.log
> /q
> TRANSFORMS=1033.mst
> AGREETOLICENSE=yes
> ADDLOCAL=Server
> ```